# TimePicker Dialog retrieves on create time, not current time if activity remains open it wont change

Tags: android, timepicker

TimePicker Dialog retrieves onCreate time, not current time if activity remains open it wont change ... I am wanting the dialog to always show current time not just when the activity started.  i am currently using the following in the onCreate:

```
    final Calendar onscene = Calendar.getInstance();
    buildingfireonsceneHour = onscene.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    buildingfireonsceneMinute = onscene.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: You want to update the TimePicker like a clock? There's a `Chronometer` class in the API, complete with a suitable little demo [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ChronometerDemo.html).

Comment: Why a picker?  if you want the current time just grab it from Calendar.

Comment: I am using it as a running time stamp while the app is open, but I also want the result to be editable via picker
*thank you, Jens, but a chronometer doesnt quite fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the updateTimer() function the current time just before you open the dialog, for example:

```
    mTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, null, 0, 0, false);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            mTimePickerDialog.updateTime(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            mTimePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

** Addition **

I believe you want to override the onPrepareDialog() function like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog (int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog, args);
    if(id != DATE_DIALOG_ID) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        ((TimePickerDialog) dialog).updateTime(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }
}
```

Comment: `final Calendar enroute = Calendar.getInstance();
  buildingfireenrouteHour.updateTime(Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
  buildingfireenrouteHour.show();

  buildingfireenrouteHour = enroute.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  buildingfireenrouteMinute = enroute.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  updateDisplay2();`

I get the error:  Multiple markers at this line
 - calendar cannot be resolved
 - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method get(int) from the type Calendar

Comment: I see a few errors, but not the big picture. Foremost, what is the name of your TimePickerDialog variable? Really it would be easiest if you post your code in your question.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand where to implement that code, I apologize, i am fairly new and teaching myself as I go

Comment: That's ok, put at the bottom of your class after your onCreateDialog(...) function. Also I believe you need the `@Override` on the line before onCreateDialog(...), just like the onPrepareDialog(...).